# JQuery automatic click after 4 sec

Tags: jquery, click, greasemonkey

I'm not an programmer, but I know something. I need very simple script for GreaseMonkey (JQuery). Script which after 4 sec click on link (http://ptzplace.eu/login.php here is it). I need script which click on "Login click" after 4 sec.

BTW. It's simulator and u can put in login and password anything u want for test.

Regards

Comment: Thanks for the job offer but the wage is too low.

Answer (score 4):

[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) && jQuerys [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) should do it:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#login_button_id').trigger('click');
}, 4e3);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/WTJgt/9/

**update**

In reference to your comment, just change the selector. Query by classname:

```
$('.logIn').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

But what if button doesn't have an id? Look at the source, it's only class. look at source ptzplace.eu ;): `<a class="signIn" href="#" onClick="doLogin(); return false;"></a>`

Comment: You might want to look at how jQuery selectors work ( http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ ) -- you don't need to have an id.