# Run a jQuery .click event on an element every 5 seconds repetitively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element which I want to be "clicked" every 5 seconds, *does something*, and then after 5 seconds it gets clicked again, *does something*, ect'.

So I used setTimeout, which does the job for the 5 seconds thing:
(found the example here: [How to hide a div after some time period?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2426304/how-to-hide-a-div-after-some-time-period))

And there's the jQuery event .trigger which I found here: [JQuery automatic click after 4 sec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818237/jquery-automatic-click-after-4-sec)

I tried looping it using 'for' and I got a .click event that happens after the first 5 seconds, and then uses the .click event again and again without the 5 seconds pause: http://jsfiddle.net/WTJgt/417/

In general, I built my first jQuery rotator :)!

with right and left buttons - and I want it to move a slide after x seconds by clicking it "without clicking".

This is my .click event code for the "next" element button:

```
// variables     
var rotCounter = 0;
var moveInPixles = 0; 
var nunSlides = 4; // Enter the number of slides

$(".r-arrow").click(function(){

    moveInPixles = ( rotCounter + 1) * 746 * -1;
    moveInPixles += 'px'; 

    $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', moveInPixles);

    rotCounter++;

    $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
    $(".dot:eq("+rotCounter+")").css('background-color', 'yellow');  

    if (rotCounter == nunSlides) {
        rotCounter = 0; 
        $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', 0);
        $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
        $(".dot:eq("+rotCounter+")").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setInterval(function () {
    $(".r-arrow").click();
}, 5000);
```

**Edit**:

Use `setInterval` and `clearInterval` so that you can reset the interval on button click. Your code needs refactoring because you can't really use it as it is.

```
var intervalId;
var rotCounter = 0;
var moveInPixles = 0; 
var nunSlides = 4; // Enter the number of slides

autoRotate();

function autoRotate() {

    intervalId = window.setInterval(function () {
        rotateStuff();
    }, 5000);
}

function rotateStuff() {

    moveInPixles = (rotCounter + 1) * 746 * -1;
    moveInPixles += 'px';

    $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', moveInPixles);

    rotCounter++;

    $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
    $(".dot:eq(" + rotCounter + ")").css('background-color', 'yellow');

    if (rotCounter == nunSlides) {
        rotCounter = 0;
        $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', 0);
        $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
        $(".dot:eq(" + rotCounter + ")").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    }
}

$('.r-arrow').on('click', function () {

    window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    rotateStuff();
    autoRotate();
});
```

Comment: This one works - only problem with it is that if i click on the right arrow from choice, and it takes me 4 seconds, on the fifth second it slides the slide right away (and accidentally slide 2 instead of one). any idea how to fix that?

Comment: slides slide every 5 seconds works, but the buttons stopped responding when clicking on them.

Comment: I can't tell. If this is so, you should see an error in your js console.

Comment: hmm.. I changed `$('.r-arrow').on('click', function () {` to: `$('.r-arrow').click(function(){` and seems like it's working, what is the difference? why did you chose to use `$('.r-arrow').on('click', function () {` ?

Answer (score 2):

Dont do a click, but just trigger the javascript function every five seconds. by triggering a click you also activate all other functions listening to the event and some might be in conflict with your code or used by other libraries.

You can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to do so.

Your code should looks like this :

```
// variables     
var rotCounter = 0;
var moveInPixles = 0; 
var nunSlides = 4; // Enter the number of slides

var myFunction = function(){

    moveInPixles = ( rotCounter + 1) * 746 * -1;
    moveInPixles += 'px'; 

    $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', moveInPixles);

    rotCounter++;

    $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
    $(".dot:eq("+rotCounter+")").css('background-color', 'yellow');  

    if (rotCounter == nunSlides) {
        rotCounter = 0; 
        $(".rotator-container").css('margin-left', 0);
        $(".dot").css('background-color', 'white');
        $(".dot:eq("+rotCounter+")").css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } 

});

$(".r-arrow").click(myFunction);

setInterval(myFunction, 5000);
```

It is important to assign `setInterval` to a variable then you will be able to stop it using [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(code, delay);
```

Then when you need to stop it :

```
window.clearInterval(intervalID)
```

Comment: I dont stop the slide in any way.. so I guess I don't need `intervalID`. 
I changed my code to the one you wrote and it's not working. what can be the problem? :S

Comment: I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WTJgt/419/) and it works so syntax looks good. I guess you forgot to close a statement or something.

Comment: And you can use `cleanInterval()` to stop the current one when you click from choice and then restart it at 5s to not have the 4s click effect you take about ;)

Comment: seems like your code on jsfiddle works, I will try it in a sec on my file.

Comment: I made a copy paste on your code, and now it's not sliding & left and right buttons dont respond.

Comment: My code is just an exemple, I don't have much details about your actual project so you need to understand what I did and apply it on your case (stack overflow is not here to do your work but help you to find a solution). If you can't apply it, it is probably you do not understand, or do not try to understand. Difficult to learn stuff by copy/pasting :D. It is a very easy problem, spend some time reviewing your code I am sure you will figure a way to make it work in few minutes.

Comment: I know but maybe im typing something wrong so I copy-paste after I try doing it myself... 
I'll try again in a few minutes, and in worst case scenario I'll work on a fiddle that simulates my slider so you can see the full code.
I'll keep updating here while working :) 
Thanks for you help and attention btw !

Answer (score 1):

Would do the trick

```
var rightArrowIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
   $(".r-arrow").trigger('click');
}, 5000);
```

In your `click` event add at

```
$(".r-arrow").click(function(){
    window.clearInterval(rightArrowIntervalId);
    // will destroy existing interval

    moveInPixles = ( rotCounter + 1) * 746 * -1;
     .....

    // will create new interval in 5 seconds
    rightArrowIntervalId = setInterval(function(){
       $(".r-arrow").trigger('click');
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: This one works - only problem with it is that if i click on the right arrow from choice, and it takes me 4 seconds, on the fifth second it slides the slide right away (and accidentally slide 2 instead of one). any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Try this new way. If I have understood what you want, you can click on arrow, but does not want 2 intervals, just 1, and next will e after 5 secods from click

Answer (score 0):

Use **setInterval** function instead of setimeout

```
     $( function() {
    $('#login').click(function() {
        alert('login button clicked');
    });
        setInterval(function() {
            $('#login').trigger('click');
        }, 500);

});
```

check updated [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/prashantptapase/WTJgt/418/)

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but if you want to call a function every 5 seconds rather than just once then use setInterval().